# endless erors within my logical operator if statement

Tags: java

im pretty new to java, as such i am unsure of how fix the errors on my codes,
trying out a logical operator on java but got overwhelmed the with the repetitive errors on every statement lines
("illegal start of type", "illegal start of expression", "not a statement" and " ';' expected")
did i use the wrong form of code?

```
   if (gender = "m") {
        if (age >=18 & <30 && vo2max >= 40 && <=60){
            EligibleSport = "Basketball";
        }
        if (age >= 18 & <26 && vo2max >= 62 & <=74){
            EligibleSport = "Biycling";
        }
        if (age >= 18 & <26 && vo2max >= 55 & <=67){
            EligibleSport = "Canoeing";
        }
        if (age >= 18 & <22 && vo2max >= 52 & <=58){
            EligibleSport = "Gymnastics";
        }
        if (age >= 10 & <25 && vo2max >= 50 & <=70){
            EligibleSport = "Swimming";
        }
```

Comment: I take just one line as example `age >=18 & <30 && vo2max >= 40 && <=60` => `age >=18 && age <30 && vo2max >= 40 && vo2max <=60` AND `gender = m` => `gender == m`

Comment: `gender = "m"` is not a comparison. It's an assignment.
Looks like there are a lot of syntax errors in your code.

Comment: ```age >=18 & <30``` is not a statement, think you looking for ```age >= 18 &&  age < 30```, plus use gender.equals("m")

Comment: Also, why a single `eligibleSport` is assigned if the conditions are overlapping (may be true) for the same input values?  For example, for `age = 20` and `vo2max=55` only _"Biycling"_ is not eligible.

Answer (score 2):

### Issues

1. The comparison operators are generally binary operators. So they need two parameters.
2. Java expects comparisons to return `boolean` and that is achieved by `&&` or `||`. Some of the operators used in the question as bitwise `&` and they will return `boolean` only if the operand is `boolean`. If incorrectly used to eventually result in `boolean`, it will return unexpected results
3. string should be compared with "equals" or "equalsIgnoreCase`

### Solution

```java
        if ("m".equals(gender)) {
            if (age >= 18 && age < 30 && vo2max >= 40 && vo2max <= 60) {
                eligibleSport = "Basketball";
            }
            if (age >= 18 && age < 26 && vo2max >= 62 && vo2max <= 74) {
                eligibleSport = "Biycling";
            }
            if (age >= 18 && age < 26 && vo2max >= 55 && vo2max <= 67) {
                eligibleSport = "Canoeing";
            }
            if (age >= 18 && age < 22 && vo2max >= 52 && vo2max <= 58) {
                eligibleSport = "Gymnastics";
            }
            if (age >= 10 && age < 25 && vo2max >= 50 && vo2max <= 70) {
                eligibleSport = "Swimming";
            }
        }
```